# Get jQuery post array values in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Using j Query post some data are posting. Firebug console Post are given below. How can I get tags[] result in Laravel controller page. Please check my laravel code below, $request->tags result is not getting some errors are showing "preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array". Please help me to solve this issue.

**Fire bug console**

```
createdby    1
tagcategoryid   1
tags[]  Music
tags[]  Reading
tags[]  test
tags[]  test1
tags[]  test2
tags[]  test3
```

**Laravel Code**

```
public function store(InterestRequest $request)
    {
        $tag = new Tag;
        $tag->tagcategory_id  = $request->tagcategoryid;
        $tag->title_de        = $request->tags;
        $tag->title_en        = $request->tags;
        $tag->suggestion      = 'no';
        $tag->created_by      = $request->createdby;
        $tag->save();
    }
```

Comment: Because if I remember, you have to set an option if you are using post in Laravel. And you have to manage with `csrf-token`

Comment: @Zl3n, I didn't get. Could you please explain?

Comment: There is the documentation here : http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token . I'm not sure it is your problem, but me, I've got problems with that, while sending data via post in jQuery

Comment: @Zl3n, If I am using  dummy data like test. it is working fine.                                                                                            $tag->title_de        = 'test';
$tag->title_en        = 'test';

Comment: so I don't understand what's your problem

Comment: @Zl3n, let me explain. I have an array tags[], posting via jquery. How can I get array in laravel controller page. I used $request->tags for getting arrays. But it's not working. Is this the correct format to collect array?

Comment: What jQuery AJAX method have you used? $.post or $.get or $.ajax? I suggest $.get() for testing as you wont have to deal with CSRF token.

Comment: what happens if you use `\Input::get('tags') instead?

Comment: Ok, maybe because you haven't use the right format in your routes.php : Router::post('test', 'InterestRequestController@store');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have applied foreach. It works for me.

```
public function store(InterestRequest $request)
    {
        foreach(Input::get('tags') as $tags) {
            $tag = new Tag;
            $tag->tagcategory_id = $request->tagcategoryid;
            $tag->title_de = $tags;
            $tag->title_en = $tags;
            $tag->suggestion = 'no';
            $tag->created_by = $request->createdby;
            $tag->save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **$request->tags post value is an array**. And your are trying to set a string field type with an array. You have to loop through your tags in this case.

Probably this will solve your proplem:

```
public function store(InterestRequest $request)
{
    foreach($request->input('tags') as $tag) {
       Tag::create(array(
           'tagcategory_id' => $request->input('tagcategoryid'),
           'title_de'       => $tag,
           'title_en'       => $tag,
           'suggestion'     => 'no';
           'created_by'     => $request->input('createdby'),
       ))
    }
}
```